# Adding buttons dynamically to JFrame or a layeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

```
public ChessGameDemo(){
Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

//  Using a Layered Pane 
layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
add(layeredPane);
layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,700));

//Create a reset button that will reset the game
JButton button = new JButton("Reset");
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
add(button,BorderLayout.EAST);


//Add the chessboard to the Layered Pane 

chessBoard = new JPanel();
layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
chessBoard.setLayout( new GridLayout(8, 8) );
chessBoard.setPreferredSize( boardSize );
chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    chessBoard.add( square );

int row = (i / 8) % 2;
if (row == 0)
    square.setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.white );
else
    square.setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.blue );
}
```

As you can see here, I am creating a chess board in a panel and adding that to a layered pane, which in turn is part of the frame. The idea is to have a menu bar and a couple of buttons to make it all look more presentable. But when I try to add the button it captures the entire height of the frame ignoring the dimension I have specified. I just see one tall button stretching the entire height of the window/frame. What is the mistake here? How do I add normal sized buttons dynamically here? that sits well next to the chessboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I try to add the button it captures the entire height of the frame ignoring the dimension I have specified.

That is the way BorderLayout.EAST works. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

You can always nest layout manager to get your desired look for example:

```
JPanel east = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
JPanel buttons = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
east.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
buttons.add( button1 );
buttons.add( button2 );
frame.add(east, BorderLayoutEAST);
```